# How to show time of jQuery ajax request continuously to user

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with a header navigation and tabs.  When a user clicks any one of these tabs, an AJAX request is made using jQuery.  The url takes the tab's value as param and a loading gif is shown to the user while the request is being made.  When the request is done, the gif is replaced with the appropriate content.

Along with the gif to indicate that the user needs to wait while data is being fetched, I would also like to show them a timer where they can see how long the current fetch is taking.

I would like the timer to be shown in mm:ss:ms format.  This timer should be continuously updated as the request is running.  Is there some way to do this?  Where do I start?

Comment: There are quite literally as many ways to do this as there are users on this site :) Why don't you try posting some code of what you've tried so far, and a specific programming issue that you're stuck on?  As it is, your question reads simply as, "please just code this for me."